# how to show $\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} \frac{\phi(n+1)}{\phi(n)}= \infty$ and $\lim \inf_{n \to \infty} \frac{\phi(n+1)}{\phi(n)}= 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, number-theory, limsup-and-liminf, arithmetic-functions

Let $\phi (n)$ be the Euler's totient function . Thenhow to prove that the set $\{\dfrac{\phi(n+1)}{\phi(n)}: n \in \mathbb Z^+\}$ is unbounded above that is how to show $\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\phi(n+1)}{\phi(n)}= \infty$ ? Moreover , how to show that  $\lim \inf_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\phi(n+1)}{\phi(n)}= 0$ ?

Comment: It's a result of Somayajulu in a paper of 1950.

Comment: @MarcoCantarini : Does the proof uses too many machinery's ? Can't we make an attempt ?

Comment: @crskhr Sorry I don't have a copy.